# Interior of a set is the largest open subset (half proof)

Tags: real-analysis

Is this proof alright?Thanks for your help!
$$S\ is\ set\ in\ X$$
$$choose\ arb\ A\subseteq\ S \ where\ A\ is\ open\ in\ X$$
$$Cause\ A\ open\ ,so\ A=intA $$
$$Cause\ A\subseteq S\ ,so\ intA\subseteq intS\ ,so\ A\subseteq intS\ $$
$$Cause\ for\ any\ A\subseteq\ S\ open\ in\ X\ and\ A\subseteq\ intS\ ,so\bigcup_{A\subseteq S\ }A\subseteq\ intS$$

Comment: There are some important details missing. How do you define openness and interior? (Definitions vary.) You say "$A \subseteq S$ open." Is $S$ open or is $A$? How exactly does this ensure maximality of $\mathrm{int}(S)$ (that is, if $T$ is an open subset of $S$ and contains $\mathrm{int}(S)$, then $T = \mathrm{int}(S)$)?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have established that any open set $A \subseteq S$ also satisfies $ A \subseteq \textrm{int} S$. To conclude the proof you just need to mention (it comes directly from definition) that $\textrm{int} S$ is an open set.